If whistle voice = super high headvoice, then can I use high falsetto to learn whistle note?
Soo I want to learn whistle tone, and I can do falsetto but not headvoice.
I heard people say that whistle is super high headvoice, can I use falsetto instead in place of headvoice to learn whistle voice?
I want to learn to whistle like Mariah Carey's emotions or Ariana Grande's whistle voice.



I'm learning from here



And



